# Creating a table or view from one field in other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know this may be quite simple, but its very late and for the life of me I cannot remember how to do it.

I have four tables, A,B and C.  Each one has an ID, Name and some other columns.

What I need is a table E that has ID, Name_A, Name_B and Name_C . So if I add another name to say B, it will update this new E table to contain it as well.

I tried creating a view:

```
Create View VwNames
as
SELECT        dbo.TableA.name AS NameA, 
              dbo.TableB.name AS NameB, 
              dbo.TableC.name AS NameC

FROM          dbo.TableA, 
              dbo.TableB, 
              dbo.TableC
```

But I was getting a view with repeated names, for example

```
Juan   Pedro  Mario
Juan   Mario  Pedro
Mario  Juan   Pedro
Mario  Pedro  Juan
Pedro  Juan   Mario
Pedro  Mario  Juan
```

What I need is something that shows me:

```
Juan
Mario
Pedro
```

Or

```
Juan Mario Pedro
```

Any help would be really appreciated I've been searching for hours now.

Thanks a lot in advance

EDIT:

How my views is looking as of now:

[image: Current View]

Comment: please use join & distinct.share the columns in tableA,B,C.There must be an id column to join

Comment: @Anand I tried using cross joint but I still got repeated names in the view. I know this may be facepalm worthy but I'm running on fumes right now

Comment: This is cartesian product.Without join you are sure to get this.Try with join or go with union

Comment: Trying the solutions given below right now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a union. Like this:

```
SELECT dbo.TableA.name FROM dbo.TableA UNION
SELECT dbo.TableB.name FROM dbo.TableB UNION
SELECT dbo.TableC.name FROM dbo.TableC
```

This will get you to output:

```
Juan
Mario
Pedro
```

Comment: please add 'distinct' to all statements

Comment: @Anand I think Union will give distinct

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar : Yes a union get the distinct values

Comment: This works 100% before accepting an answer I wanna try the others to see how they work.

Answer (score 1):

TRY LIKE THIS :

```
Create View VwNames
as

SELECT    distinct    dbo.TableA.name AS NameA, 
              dbo.TableB.name AS NameB, 
              dbo.TableC.name AS NameC

FROM          dbo.TableA TA LEFT JOIN
              ON TA.col1=TB.col1
              dbo.TableB TB LEFT JOIN
              ON TB.col1=T.col1
              dbo.Table T
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Create View VwNames
as
SELECT        distinct a.name AS NameA, 
              b.name AS NameB, 
              c.name AS NameC

FROM          dbo.TableA a join
              dbo.TableB b 
            on b.id=a.id
            join 
              dbo.Table c
            on c.id=b.id
```